# Combining information from multiple lines based on overlapping positions

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics

I am looking to combine information from multiple lines based on specific conditions.

This is my output:

```
ATAT 0 2 2
TATA 1 3 2
ATAT 2 4 2
TATA 3 5 2
GGGG 7 9 2
CCCC 11 13 2
GGGG 32 34 2
```

The first column is a substring,
second column is the start position of the substring within the larger string,
third column is the end position of the substring,
fourth column is the number of 2 character units within the substring (ATAT has two units of "AT").

My goal is to combine adjacent substrings and output the new substring, position, and sum. For example, in the above output there are two cases of "ATAT" that are adjacent (1st and 3rd rows). We know they are adjacent because the end position of the first ATAT is the start position of the second "ATAT."
So my desired output would look like:

```
ATATATAT 0 4 4
TATATATA 1 5 4
GGGG 7 9 2
CCCC 11 13 2
GGGG 32 34 2
```

Note that the new positions for each string are the start position for the first string encountered and the end position for the last string encountered.

My hunch is that this could be done by
1) making a dictionary of these values such that (ATAT:0,2,2)
2) iterate over the original file and pull out instance where the substrings match and where the start of one is equal to the end of the other,
3) print the summed + concatenated results to a new file.

However, this seems rather un-elegant. Are there any more efficient ways to accomplish this? Thanks.

EDIT: @cdlane, when using the following input and script below (adjusted to deal with comma delimiter):
INPUT:

```
AT,0,2
TA,1,3
AT,2,4
TA,3,5
AT,4,6
TA,5,7
AG,6,8
GG,7,9
GG,8,10
GG,9,11
GC,10,12
CC,11,13
CC,12,14
CC,13,15
CG,14,16
GC,15,17
CT,16,18
TG,17,19
GC,18,20
CT,19,21
TG,20,22
GA,21,23
AC,22,24
CG,23,25
GG,24,26
GA,25,27
AC,26,28
CG,27,29
GT,28,30
TT,29,31
TT,30,32
TG,31,33
GG,32,34
GG,33,35
GG,34,36
```

OUTPUT:
     **('ATAT', '0', '4')**
    ('TATA', '1', '5')
    ('GC', '10', '12')
    ('CCCC', '11', '15')
    ('CC', '12', '14')
    ('CG', '14', '16')
    ('GC', '15', '17')
    ('CT', '16', '18')
    ('TG', '17', '19')
    ('GC', '18', '20')
    ('CT', '19', '21')
    ('TG', '20', '22')
    ('GA', '21', '23')
    ('AC', '22', '24')
    ('CG', '23', '25')
    ('GG', '24', '26')
    ('GA', '25', '27')
    ('AC', '26', '28')
    ('CG', '27', '29')
    ('GT', '28', '30')
    ('TT', '29', '31')
    ('TT', '30', '32')
    ('TG', '31', '33')
    ('GGGG', '32', '36')
    ('GG', '33', '35')
    **('AT', '4', '6')**
    ('TA', '5', '7')
    ('AG', '6', '8')
    ('GGGG', '7', '11')
    ('GG', '8', '10')

Comment: you could try something then. Because the description is good, but code is better.

Comment: Will the value of 2nd and 3rd columns be unique from others in the same column in a single run?

Comment: I don't understand the initial description.  For instance, "ATAT" is four characters long, and starts at position 0 of the "larger string".  How can it end at position 2?  The end position is start+length-1, which is 3 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the (revised) input is well behaved (sorted, no overlaps, etc.) then we should be able to get away with combining the two main loops, and eliminating the deletion during iteration by making the end positions the keys and checking if each starting position, as it's read, is in the dictionary:

```
import sys

dictionary = dict()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as source:
    for line in source:
        substring, start, end = line.rstrip().split(",")

        start = int(start)
        units = len(substring) // 2

        if start in dictionary:
            ext_substring, ext_start, ext_units = dictionary[start]

            if substring * ext_units == ext_substring:
                del dictionary[start]
                substring += ext_substring
                start = ext_start
                units += ext_units

        dictionary[int(end)] = (substring, start, units)

for end in sorted(dictionary, key=lambda key: dictionary[key][1]):
    substring, start, units = dictionary[end]
    print(substring, start, end, units, sep=",")
```

This gives the output:

```
ATATAT,0,6,3
TATATA,1,7,3
AG,6,8,1
GGGG,7,11,2
GG,8,10,1
GC,10,12,1
CCCC,11,15,2
CC,12,14,1
CG,14,16,1
GC,15,17,1
CT,16,18,1
TG,17,19,1
GC,18,20,1
CT,19,21,1
TG,20,22,1
GA,21,23,1
AC,22,24,1
CG,23,25,1
GG,24,26,1
GA,25,27,1
AC,26,28,1
CG,27,29,1
GT,28,30,1
TT,29,31,1
TT,30,32,1
TG,31,33,1
GGGG,32,36,2
GG,33,35,1
```

This input is disturbing as it represents an overlap, the handling of which has not been discussed:

```
GG,32,34
GG,33,35
GG,34,36
```